# How do I change modals icon in Slack?

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit

Unable to find anything in the documentation. https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This icon is taken from your App's icon and cannot be changed on a per-modal basis.
Until you have no icon specified - the default one is used like on your screenshot.